# Best Index to use for DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a table called "posts" which stores online blogs and articles. The data structure is different depending on the type of post. For now, there are 3: news, how-to, and vlog. Two more may be added in the future.

My table has the following attributes:

category (HASH)
timestamp (RANGE)

I want to be able to pull only a few fields that are common to all posts (postId, title, postDate, author, category) from the table and limit the recordset to 10 records per page whenever a search term is found in ANY of the fields.

I also want to be able to pull every field when a postId is specified (postID is not a key field but it is unique).

What is the best way to accomplish this with DynamoDB?

Answer (score 0):

> I also want to be able to pull every field when a postId is specified
>   (postID is not a key field but it is unique).

This can be easily done using an index on `postId`, selecting all projected attributes.

> I want to be able to pull only a few fields that are common to all
>   posts (postId, title, postDate, author, category) from the table and
>   limit the recordset to 10 records per page whenever a search term is
>   found in ANY of the fields.

This is a bit tricky, as it's more of a search problem, most suitable for ElasticSearch, for example. You could use both these solutions, depending on your querying needs.

Comment: On point #2, how is Elastic Search implemented? Is that a separate service from AWS?